# Supabase Flutter ORM

Tags: flutter, supabase

I am pretty new to Supabase, but not to Flutter iself. I already implemented applications with Firebase and MongoDB Realm.

I am currently struggling with two things, that I didnt have to worry about with the other libraries:

1. Whats the recommended way to implement the classes representing my tables? Making the fields required that would be required in the database doesn't really work. E.g. when creating an Object, I have no id yet, so I couldnt make it mandatory.
2. How/When should I load relations of that table? When I show a list of teams, I would not want team.members to be set, but when I open the team I expect to load those. But this is not very safe it seems.

With Supabase not having an ORM, how are you dealing with these problems?